# Remote Jacoco Agent in a Spring Boot not generate report

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I’m launching a spring boot application using the `jacocoagent.jar` with these JVM arguments:

```
-javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=port=6300,address=*,destfile=jacoco-remote.exec,output=tcpserver
```

In the `build.gradle`
 file I have the next config for jacoco plugin:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}

test {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
    }
}

e2eTest {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
        address = "localhost"
        port = 6300
    }
}

e2eTest.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```

When I launch test task for local unit tests coverage report, the test.exec is created in the build/jacoco directory with the html and xml report in the reports/jacoco directory.

But when I launch the e2eTest task through the remote agent the e2eTest.exec file is created in the build/jacoco directory, but not the html or xml report, in any directory.

Any of you know if I need other configuration or if I started the app with the corrects JMV arguments of the jacocoagent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running gradle with the `--debug` option at command line. It should tell you a bit more about what's going on. It's probably SKIPPED because the default exec file doesn't exist (or maybe it's UP-TO-DATE)

It's possible/likely you'll need a `JacocoReport` task for each test task. With each report task driven by its own `exec` file

Comment: First, thanks for your respond. In the project I have configured jacoco per each task:

```
test {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
    }
}

e2eTest {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
        address = "localhost"
        port = 6300
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway I have launched with `--debug` option but the information that I have seen looks good:

```
[org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :jacocoTestReport' started[org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.jacoco to root project 'examples'' completed
[org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension] Applying Jacoco to e2eTest
```

But the problem persist :)

Comment: You can't use the `jacocoTestReport` to generate two different reports. You'll need to add another task of type `JacocoReport`. Each test task generates its own exec file. So each test task needs it's own report task (think of the case where you want to run both test tasks and generate both reports)

Comment: Ok. I just tried with only one `jacocoTestReport` for `e2eTest` task. The e2eTest.exec is generated but the report not.

Comment: Have you configured the report task to use the correct exec file as input?

Comment: Correct. I just needed to include `executionData = fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/e2eTest.exec")` in `jacocoTestReport` task. Thanks :)

Comment: As I said, you should have two independent report tasks, each one driven by its own exec file